# jquery onclick event with parameter

Tags: jquery, onclick

I have a table of div's and every time i click one I'd like to get a pop up. They will all be in a different place. So I thought that the best way of doing this would be jQuery.

I found a balloon pop up tutorial for jQuery... and I got a pop up. but I'm struggling on a lot of things.

how do i initiate a jQuery function from an onclick event and pass in an ID parameter as a selector?

This is the code that I am using just to try get it working:

```
$(function() {
  $('div').showBalloon( {
    contents: "hello"
  }).toggle(
    function() {$(this).hideBalloon(); },
    function() {$(this).showBalloon(); }
  );
});
```

where showBalloon is from a jQuery plugin.
so instead of $('div') i'd like to use a function parameter.. Does this make sense?

Comment: Do you want to pass a selector as a parameter to a function?

Comment: i think so.. so instead of $('div') i would want the id of the div that I'm clicking.

Comment: bet you can tell that I'm new to this :p

Comment: To pass the ID as the selector:
$('#yourIDhere').(click(function () {/*TODO*/})
Is that what you mean?

Comment: sorry i have actually just realised how retarded this question is. thanks anyway, i don't know enough jQuery for this

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I pass arguments in .click() function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31939369/how-can-i-pass-arguments-in-click-function)