# How can I pass arguments in .click() function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to pass arguments to the `click()` handler function in the following case:

```
function edit_tab(val){
    var prev_tab = $("#current_tab").html();
    if (prev_tab == 1) {
        $('.edit-basic-info').click(a); // here I want to pass some argument "a".
    }
}
```

How can I pass the argument a in the above code? The way I am trying to do is not working.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3273350/jquery-click-pass-parameters-to-user-function, check it here ,and this will be more help full http://jsfiddle.net/GDGXA/

Comment: I don't believe this is a duplicate - the other questions ask how to pass additional parameters to a named function, this on the other hand is asking how to pass additional parameters to an event handler

Comment: @billyonecan I don't see how this *isn't* a duplicate.  Both questions ask how to pass additional arguments to the function being passed to the `.click()` function (in this question, the function is 'a' and in the original question it is named 'add_event'. (also note that this question was closed by a gold badge holder, I'm more inclined to trust their opinion over yours as to whether or not this is a duplicate)

Comment: Agreed, just because the intent is different doesn't negate the duplicate status. Both questions deal with how to pass custom parameters along with the click event. This is a duplicate.

Comment: @billyonecan And what would be the point of passing parameter `a` to the click event if you're not intending to pass it to the function that handles the click event?

Comment: My apologies, it is indeed a duplicate. Looking at it again I've no idea why I thought it wasn't.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `trigger()'s` `extraParameters` to pass additional parameters to your handler:

From the [`trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) documentation:

> extraParameters Type: Array or PlainObject Additional parameters to
>   pass along to the event handler.

Example (also from the documentation):

```
$( "#foo" ).on( "custom", function( event, param1, param2 ) {
  alert( param1 + "\n" + param2 );
});

$( "#foo").trigger( "custom", [ "Custom", "Event" ] );
```

Comment: yeah! this works for me, thanks a lot man, you saved my time :)

Answer (score 3):

Use a closure:

```
function doSomething(myParam) {
    return function(event) {
        // Use both myParam and event here
    };
}
```

And in your event handler:

```
$('#foo').on('click', doSomething('parameter')); // Works fine
```

The reason this works is that the call to `doSomething('parameter')` **returns a function**, the inner function is not executed until the click handler calls it, and it can use all of the parameters passed to it from the outside.

Comment: But there is no way here to pass a separate value of the parameter on each click, depending on context. Each click may require a separate value of the parameter to be passed to decide how the event handler should handle the event.

Answer (score -1):

```
    <script>
    function edit_tab(val){
                var prev_tab=$("#current_tab").html();
                if(prev_tab==1){
                    $('.edit-basic-info').bind('click', function () {  
                       fndosomething(a)
//pass value in that function and use it

     });
                }
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: Could you expand upon your code (edit, not comment)? Why should your solution work?

Answer (score -1):

bit more you can do like this

```
var message = 'check'; 
$('button').click({msg: message},functionFoo);

function functionFoo(e){
 alert(e.data.msg);
}
```